# UML use case - who is the actor?

Tags: uml, diagram, actor, behavior, use-case

The UML 2.4 documentation defines an actor as following:

> An actor specifies a role played by a user or any other system that interacts with the subject.

In my case, the subject is a web service provided by a Soccer Association. The operations of the service are the 4 ones in the middle. Now, the website (or a web application) is the one which really interacts with the system (web service), but it won't do it by itself; it needs a user.

So, who is the actor?

Below you have an example of how I thought the diagram should look like, but I have doubts regarding its correctness.

[image]

Comment: I would say that "Visit the web page of the soccer club" is not a use case. What is the fan's goal in visiting the web page? It's to get the fixture list or results or a live score or ladder positions. Simply visiting the web site is just time-wasting if it doesn't fulfill some goal. So remove "Visit the web page of the soccer club" and have associations directly from the Fan actor to each of the four main goal-oriented use cases.

Comment: All three are actors.

Comment: And how should I represent this?

Comment: @chimp: I think you are right. I'm going for your approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have one remark, and that's about the title 'Asking information use case'. The outer rectangle is the system boundary, so maybe 'Asking information system' would be more convenient. It is actually not a use case, it's the complete system you are describing.

Edit: after the change of the diagram: i would make the relationship between the 'visit webpage' use case and the other use cases as an 'include' (with the arrow pointing away from the visit webpage use case). 
Then i would tend to agree with it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I figured out that the package name is wrong after uploading the file... Maybe I could just delete the package... But does the fact that you have only one remark that the diagram is well done? Is the fan the main actor and visiting the web page just a use case?

Comment: Are you sure the meteorological agency is going to get the weather forecast out of your system ?  :)

Comment: The meteorological agency is there because it is the actor providing the weather web service. At least that's what I think.

Comment: I changed my answer to the final version (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

I would split the use-case diagram into two diagrams. One for the web application and the other for the web service, since these are really  two different systems.

In the first diagram, there will be two actors: the fan and the web service.

In the second diagram, there will be three systems actors: the web application, the Soccer Association, and the meteorological agency.

This splitting has the advantage that you can think of more use cases for the web applications without getting bogged down the details of the web service -- these two ideally should be independent systems.